# Strava reconnecting issue

Tags: php, laravel, strava

I have connect with strava and got data via Socialite package in PHP Laravel. And extract data without no issues. But recently i can't connect to the strava again. It show ans exception.

```
$stravaUser = Socialite::driver('strava')->user(); // this line shown error
```

The error was:

`local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException'` with message `'Undefined index: email'` in `c:\my web folder\vendor\socialiteproviders\strava\Provider.php:57`

Comment: Try this, Composer update in command prompt... Maybe, Error Remove..

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in a recent [commit](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/commit/c5d3fcbe4b5705d9e426fdf9241b727bb51703f7) but has yet to be included in release so you need to use the dev-master for now.

In your composer.json, replace:

```
"socialiteproviders/strava": "^3.0"
```

with

```
"socialiteproviders/strava": "dev-master"
```

And run

```
$ composer update
```